# Why would TALISE be directed to the shore of Ligeia Mare?

Tags: probe, life, lander, titan, talise

[TALISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_Lake_In-situ_Sampling_Propelled_Explorer) (Titan Lake In-situ Sampling Propelled Explorer) is a proposed automated boat that would float in a lake called Ligeia Mare on Saturn's moon Titan.

I saw [an article](http://www.space.com/17829-titan-lakes-boat-talise-mission.html) that said once it touches down in the lake, TALISE would begin working its way toward the shore of the lake. There are some people who think [life could be found on Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_on_Titan), which is one of the reasons people want to explore it (but also, how cool would it be to send a boat through space?), do they think that life might be easier to find closer to shore? Is there another reason they want to move toward shore?

[image]
<sup>From a [Space.com](http://www.space.com/17829-titan-lakes-boat-talise-mission.html) article</sup>

Comment: Littorals yield more information.

Comment: As @DeerHunter has said, I believe that the reason they will be moving towards the shore is because it will be easier to get more information.  Firstly, at the shore it can analyze rocks, which contain information on the history of the region.  Secondly, it is probably easier to sample shallows near the shore than the deep regions in the center of the lake, just as how it is easier to explore a tide pool than the deep ocean.